# Get property in property using JsonProperty

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I work with JSON.Net.

I wrote a strongly typed representation for the expected Json :

```
public BaseClass{
         [JsonProperty("fields")]
        public Fields Fields { get; set; }
}

public class Fields
{
    [JsonProperty("worklog")]
    public List<WorkLog> WorkLog { get; set; }
}
```

Sample of expected Json :

```
    {
    "baseprop": {
        "fields": {
            "worklog": {
                "startAt": 0,
                "maxResults": 20,
                "total": 2,
                "worklogs": [
                    {
                        "self": "",
                        "author": {},
                        "updateAuthor": {},
                        "comment": "UpdatedcouriersT&C",
                        "created": "2015-09-04T19: 11: 27.169+0300",
                        "updated": "2015-09-04T19: 13: 00.567+0300",
                        "started": "2015-09-04T19: 11: 00.000+0300",
                        "timeSpent": "1h",
                        "timeSpentSeconds": 3600,
                        "id": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "self": "",
                        "author": {},
                        "updateAuthor": {},
                        "comment": "",
                        "created": "2015-09-07T10: 26: 23.549+0300",
                        "updated": "2015-09-07T10: 26: 23.549+0300",
                        "started": "2015-09-07T10: 26: 00.000+0300",
                        "timeSpent": "10m",
                        "timeSpentSeconds": 600,
                        "id": ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the value of the property "worklogs" from the "baseprop" element?
I tried something like `"[JsonProperty("worklog/worklogs")]"` but this doesn't work.

Does JsonProperty support such a thing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/readingwritingjson.htm

Comment: What do you mean by "if I am in baseprop"? It's very hard to tell exactly what you're doing, especially as your `Fields` class appears to have little to do with the JSON you've presented...

Comment: @JonSkeet, i update question. I deserialize my json and with `JsonProperty` i "bind" my classes to json properties. So i want to skip one step from `fields` to `worklogs` (skip property `worklog`)

Comment: Your JSON looks incomplete; what you have shown does not validate.  See http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @BrianRogers, now is ok

Comment: the JSON fields `summary` and `assignee` don't exist, are you sure your JSON sample is not truncated ?

Comment: Or maybe you could have a more accurate example because at the moment, it is quite misleading, and quite hard to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion comes from the fact that you are trying to remap the complete structure of your JSON to your class.

Perhaps what you should consider is not to deserialize the object, but instead use Linq to Json and assign manually the properties of your `BaseClass` object as follows :

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
BaseClass bc = new BaseClass()
bc.Assignee = jObject["fields"]["worklog"]["worklogs"].First()["assignee"].Value<string>()
```